# Cannot find the certificate using the following search criteria in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I am trying to work with [AdvCash API](https://advcash.gi/files/documents/advcash.merchantapi-1.22_en.pdf) with Asp.net. they have a webservice in [this](https://wallet.advcash.com/wsm/merchantWebService?wsdl) address.
After adding it via Service Reference, run the code below:

```
 ServiceReferenceAdvCash1.MerchantWebServiceClient Adv_Api = new ServiceReferenceAdvCash1.MerchantWebServiceClient();
            ServiceReferenceAdvCash1.walletBalanceDTO[] Balances = Adv_Api.getBalances(new ServiceReferenceAdvCash1.authDTO() { apiName = apiName, accountEmail = accountEmail, authenticationToken = token });
```

But it caused error :

> The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials

So i Specified clientCertificate in web.config:

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MerchantWebServiceSoapBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="MerchantWebServiceSoapBinding1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://wallet.advcash.com/wsm/merchantWebService"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MerchantWebServiceSoapBinding"
    contract="ServiceReferenceAdvCash1.MerchantWebService" name="MerchantWebServicePort" behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="ClientSide" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Still it gets error:

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'ClientSide'.

Should i add any certificate to the server? or is there any other solution?

Comment: the machine running the code and if you are running window wnd+R type MMC enter, then find select certificates local machine, under personal or trusted certificates you need to able to see the "ClientSide" certificate subject certicate

Comment: I could not find "ClientSide" certificate in mmc, can i add certificate?

Comment: if it is not in either folder then you need to add it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am trying to add it, but why am i do this? i mean i worked with many APIs before but i have never encounter with such an issue. is "ClientSide" certificate common or specified for a service? should i get and add AdvCash certificate to my server?